# Las animaciones se cargan antes Animate.css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy teniendo el inconveniente de que las animaciones se cargan antes de llegar al texto o la imagen que lo contiene.
Estoy usando `Animate.css`, solamente agregue el archivo a mi proyecto y lo agregue al `html` para ejecutar las funciones.
Al archivo `Animate.css` lo agregue en la parte superior del `head`.
Por ejemplo agrego varios textos y cuando carga la página muestra a todos a la vez, a diferencia de ir mostrando de a uno.

```html
        <section class="service">
            <div class="container py-5">

                <h3 class="titulo-text display-4 text-center">Nuestros Servicios</h3>
                <p class="lead text-center">Destacamos en eficiencia, compromiso, honestidad, atención al detalle y velocidad con cada equipo.</p>

                <div class="iconos row text-center">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="box-service">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#7f7f7f">
                                <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Computadora y Laptop</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">Si su equipo dejo de funcionar, no se preocupe ni se alarme, nosotros lo solucionamos, contamos con técnicos capaces de solucionar el problema para que este pueda funcionar de manera óptima y adecuada a sus requerimientos </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#0004ff">
                                <i class="fa fa-windows"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Windows y Programas</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">Reinstalamos todo el sistema operativo.<br>Instalamos todos los programas que utilizas. Windows, Office, Antivirus <br>y además si lo necesitas: Autocad, Photoshop, Illustrator, Scketchup y muchos más.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#d10000">
                                <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Limpieza de Virus</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">Eliminamos todos tipos de VIRUS.<br>Ya no tendrás publicidad molesta en tu navegador ni en tu escritorio.<br>Tampoco reiterados reinicios o apagones.<br>Utilizar tu equipo de manera mas eficiente<br></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#302977">
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Recuperacion y Proteccion</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">No tienes que dar por perdida tu información, somos capaces de recuperarla, tratarla y entregarte un recovery, con la mayor eficacia y confiabilidad.<br>La informacion de un cliente es lo mas importante.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#479e00">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Paginas Web</h4>
                           <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">Como expertos en soluciones tecnológicas, sabemos cómo llevar tu negocio a lo digital de manera profesional. Te ayudamos a crear tu página web con un diseño actualizado a las tendencias y funciones web que tu comercio necesita.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#0075a8">
                                <i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Redes y Conexiones</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">Desde un problema con tu conexión local hasta la reparación de tu red inalámbrica o de un servidor. <br>Nuestros expertos en Redes te ayudarán a lograr la conectividad más óptima. <br>Atendemos instalación, reparación y mantenimiento de redes</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con CSS puro no es posible, hay que utilizar un poco de *Javascript* para detectar cuando un elemento está visible en el *viewport* usando la API de [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), asignando una clase temporal y cambiándola a la que realizará la animación cuando el elemento comience a mostrarse.

Hay dos variables importantes a tener en cuenta:

- **startRatio:** Es el porcentaje visible del objeto donde se creará la animación (0 = 0%, 1 = 100%)
- **options.threshold:** Porcentaje visible del objeto para disparar la función y comenzar a comparar para saber en qué momento aplicar la animación

Dentro de la función se recorren todos los elementos *observados* y hay que comparar la "visibilidad" actual con la primera variable.

**Nota:** La visibilidad no se refiere a la propiedad CSS, sino a la parte de cada elemento que aparece en el *viewport*; un ejemplo burdo: si tiene 10 líneas y solo ha aparecido 1, la visibilidad es del 10%.

```js
// Obtener los elementos donde aplicará la animación
let ps = document.querySelectorAll('p.anim');
// Definir el porcentaje visible para iniciar (0 - 1)
let startRatio = 0.1;
// Opciones
let options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.15
};
// Definir función para observar los elementos
function aparece(entries, observer) {
  // Recorrer elementos observados
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Si superaron el porcentaje visible
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > startRatio) {
      // Asignar clase para animar
      entry.target.className = 'animate__animated animate__backInDown';
    }
  });
}
// Inicializar observador
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(aparece, options);
// Agregar cada elemento al observador
ps.forEach(p => observer.observe(p));
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome 5 -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>
    
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">

      <h1 class="title">
        Hello World
      </h1>
        <section class="service">
            <div class="container py-5">

                <h3 class="titulo-text display-4 text-center">Nuestros Servicios</h3>
                <p class="lead text-center">Destacamos en eficiencia, compromiso, honestidad, atención al detalle y velocidad con cada equipo.</p>

                <div class="iconos row text-center">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="box-service">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#7f7f7f">
                                <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Computadora y Laptop</h4>
                            <p class="anim">Reinstalamos todo el sistema operativo.<br>Instalamos todos los programas que utilizas. Windows, Office, Antivirus <br>y además si lo necesitas: Autocad, Photoshop, Illustrator, Scketchup y muchos más.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#d10000">
                                <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Limpieza de Virus</h4>
                            <p class="anim">Eliminamos todos tipos de VIRUS.<br>Ya no tendrás publicidad molesta en tu navegador ni en tu escritorio.<br>Tampoco reiterados reinicios o apagones.<br>Utilizar tu equipo de manera mas eficiente<br></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#302977">
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Recuperacion y Proteccion</h4>
                            <p class="anim">No tienes que dar por perdida tu información, somos capaces de recuperarla, tratarla y entregarte un recovery, con la mayor eficacia y confiabilidad.<br>La informacion de un cliente es lo mas importante.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#479e00">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Paginas Web</h4>
                           <p class="anim">Como expertos en soluciones tecnológicas, sabemos cómo llevar tu negocio a lo digital de manera profesional. Te ayudamos a crear tu página web con un diseño actualizado a las tendencias y funciones web que tu comercio necesita.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues solo tendrias que agregar esta clase `animate__delay-2s` a tu p tag.

```
<div class="animate__animated animate__bounce animate__delay-2s">Example</div>
```

Aqui puedes ejecutarlo y ver como quedan con 2s, 3s, 4s, y 5s que les agregue en los p tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome 5 -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>
    
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">

      <h1 class="title">
        Hello World
      </h1>
        <section class="service">
            <div class="container py-5">

                <h3 class="titulo-text display-4 text-center">Nuestros Servicios</h3>
                <p class="lead text-center">Destacamos en eficiencia, compromiso, honestidad, atención al detalle y velocidad con cada equipo.</p>

                <div class="iconos row text-center">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="box-service">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#7f7f7f">
                                <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Computadora y Laptop</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">Si su equipo dejo de funcionar, no se preocupe ni se alarme, nosotros lo solucionamos, contamos con técnicos capaces de solucionar el problema para que este pueda funcionar de manera óptima y adecuada a sus requerimientos </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#0004ff">
                                <i class="fa fa-window"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Windows y Programas</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown animate__delay-2s">Reinstalamos todo el sistema operativo.<br>Instalamos todos los programas que utilizas. Windows, Office, Antivirus <br>y además si lo necesitas: Autocad, Photoshop, Illustrator, Scketchup y muchos más.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#d10000">
                                <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Limpieza de Virus</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown animate__delay-3s">Eliminamos todos tipos de VIRUS.<br>Ya no tendrás publicidad molesta en tu navegador ni en tu escritorio.<br>Tampoco reiterados reinicios o apagones.<br>Utilizar tu equipo de manera mas eficiente<br></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#302977">
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Recuperacion y Proteccion</h4>
                            <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown animate__delay-4s">No tienes que dar por perdida tu información, somos capaces de recuperarla, tratarla y entregarte un recovery, con la mayor eficacia y confiabilidad.<br>La informacion de un cliente es lo mas importante.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                            <div class="icon" style="color:#479e00">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="info-title">Paginas Web</h4>
                           <p class="animate__animated animate__backInDown animate__delay-5s">Como expertos en soluciones tecnológicas, sabemos cómo llevar tu negocio a lo digital de manera profesional. Te ayudamos a crear tu página web con un diseño actualizado a las tendencias y funciones web que tu comercio necesita.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 feature-box">
                        <div class="hestia-info">
                
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, el problema es que si espera 5 segundos en la parte superior antes de bajar, se cargan todas las animaciones antes de verlas.

Comment: Ah ok ok ahora entiendo. Lo que necesitas es que cuando el usuario hace el scroll para abajo ahi qures que se muestre las siguientes animaciones.